# How to get HDF5 chunk dimensions in existing file?

Tags: c, hdf5

I'm writing some code to remove parts of an existing HDF5 file (some dimensions, some datasets, etc.) with the C HDF5 API. I'd like the new HDF5 file to come with the same chunk size as my existing HDF5 file, but I can't seem to find anywhere that I can retrieve current chunk dimensions. There is the H5P_GET_CHUNK function, but that retrieves chunk dimensions on dataset creation only. There is also the H5D_GET_CHUNK_STORAGE_SIZE function, which only retrieves total size (not dimensions).

Is there a way to retrieve chunk dimensions (not just total size) from an existing dataset that I'm missing?

Comment: I concur with the comments below. Chunk attributes are available in Python (which sits on top of the C API). So, there should is a way to do this in C. Have you asked at **The HDF Group** forums? Someone there should be able to explain the procedure.

Answer (score 1):

(following from https://support.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/examples/examples-by-api/hdf5-examples/1_8/C/H5D/h5ex_d_chunk.c )
You can get the data creation property list from an existing dataset with:

```
hid_t dcpl = H5Dget_create_plist(ds_id);
```

You can check if the layout is chunked with

```
H5D_layout_t layout = H5Pget_layout(dcpl);
```

And if it is, you can get the chunks with

```
if (layout == H5D_CHUNKED)
{
    hsize_t chunk_dims_out[ndims];
    H5Pget_chunk(dcpl, ndims, chunk_dims_out);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at [HDFql](http://www.hdfql.com) as it is a (much) simpler way to manipulate HDF5 files, in particular to get the storage dimensions (i.e. chunk size) of a certain dataset. As an example, if you want to get the storage dimensions of a dataset named `dset` do the following:

```
SHOW STORAGE DIMENSION dset
```

Additional information about this operation may be found in section 6.7.15 of the [reference manual](http://www.hdfql.com/resources/HDFqlReferenceManual.pdf).

Comment: It's interesting, but I'd really like to avoid integrating *another* library into this project and frankly that license scares the crap out of me. Also, the inability for me to compile the library myself is no bueno as I do want the ability to deploy code onto an HPC that uses its own MPI. Good suggestion though.

Comment: Clearly there is a way to do this within HDF5 as both h5dump and this tool can do it, but I haven't been able to untangle the spaghetti of h5dump and this project isn't open source.

Comment: @Laxsnor: according to the reference manual, HDFql does not ship its own MPI library but rather (dynamically) loads the one installed in the machine/HPC environment.